# Citrix, Linux-Host, Win-Client: Microsoft Team does not detect Audio devices

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, microsoft-teams, citrix

**Microsoft Teams** is not detecting audio devices within Microsoft Windows Citrix environment. Linux / Ubuntu host.

**How to fix audio device detection?**

**System**

- My Company uses **Citrix** for remote work.
- The OS (Operating System) is Microsoft **Windows** 10
- My local host is Linux (Ubuntu 20.04)
- Citrix Workspace Client 21.12

Comment: Is the problem input audio devices or output?

Comment: I think it was both - pls see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I could **fix detecting audio devices** in **Microsoft Teams** by installing **libc++1-12** and **libunwind-12** on the local **linux** / ubuntu 20.04 **host** :

```
curl -fsSL https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://apt.llvm.org/focal/ llvm-toolchain-focal-12 main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc++1-12 libunwind-12
```

Comment: Also answered on https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/415288-linux-host-teams-on-windows-client-does-not-detect-microphone/?source=notifications

Comment: This solved Linux Citrix Workspace connecting to Windows having MS Teams error "There's a problem with your connection" "Still connecting to remote devices. Calling isn't available yet." Audio Devices are all none, and message "Citrix HDX Not Connected".

Answer (score 0):

This problem (and the solution) is still valid on Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS. MS Teams was not recognizing any devices while the Windows 11 it was running on was able to use my speaker/microphone etc. just fine.

Executing

```
sudo apt-get install libc++-12-dev
sudo apt-get install libunwind-12
```

and restarting the Citrix client fixed this for me, now MS Teams is detecting my Jabra headset and Logitech C920 webcam.